# How to change the font size of NSAttributedString in ios7

Tags: ios7, uitextview, uislider, nsattributedstring, nslayoutmanager

I have loaded a `NSAttributedstring` to an `UITextview`. The string contains texts with different font sizes. I want to change the size of text using  `UISlider`. So i am trying to increase the font size accordingly. I can set a specific font size for the `attributedString` , but what i need is to change dynamically

```
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:dataString];
NSLayoutManager *textLayout = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:textLayout];

NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(320, 568)];
[textLayout addTextContainer:textContainer];

textview=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 50, 320, 568) textContainer:textContainer];
[self.view addSubview:textview];
```

Comment: Please add some code related to what you have already done.

Comment: @akashg have added some code